# How create a signal with checkbox in QTableWidget Pyqt6

Tags: python-3.x, qtablewidget, pyqt6, qcheckbox

I begin with python v3.10, I use actually PyQt6 for the design of the windows.

I created a QTableWidget in  which I put a checkbox with a picture.

Now I would like to create a signal to execute a function when I click on it.

I tried, connect, stateChanged, ... but nothing works.

I write below my code with a picture :

```
        while self.query.next():
        # widget checkbox
        checkbox_widget = QWidget()
        checkbox_widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: transparent;')
        w_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox

        layout_cb = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(checkbox_widget)
        layout_cb.addWidget(w_checkbox())
        layout_cb.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        layout_cb.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        checkbox_widget.setLayout(layout_cb)

        tablerow = self.table_EP.rowCount()

        self.table_EP.insertRow(tablerow)

        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((self.query.value('col1'))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((self.query.value('col2'))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((self.query.value('col3'))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((str(self.query.value('col4')))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((str(self.query.value('col5')))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((str(self.query.value('col6')))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((self.query.value('col7'))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((str(self.query.value('col8')))))
        self.table_EP.setItem(tablerow, 8, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem((str(self.query.value('col9')))))
        self.table_EP.setCellWidget(tablerow, 9, w_checkbox())
        self.table_EP.setCellWidget(tablerow, 9, checkbox_widget)

        w_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.clicked_button())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLRR0.jpg)

Thank you so much for your help (I'm sorry for my English).

Comment: Typos: remove the parentheses in `w_checkbox()` and in the connection to `self.clicked_button`, and remove the first `setCellWidget()` line.

Answer (score 0):

This is some weird code.

Ultimately you need to call `.stateChanged.connect(self.clicked_button())` on the *instance* of `QtWidgets.QCheckBox`.

You create an instance of the class `QtWidgets.QCheckBox` with this line: `layout_cb.addWidget(w_checkbox())`, but you don't assign it to a variable.

You should first assign it to a variable, then refer to it using that variable, like so:

```py
checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
layout_cb.addWidget(checkbox)
checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.clicked_button())
```

Are you sure you need the brackets after `self.clicked_button()`? That only makes sense if it returns a function.

Comment: In my opinion, those were just typos (so, the post is offtopic).

Comment: I think you're right. They must've started adding brackets here, there, and everywhere until it seemed to work.